# Asp.NET MVC: validating age > 18 having 3 combo box

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I've 3 combo box showing the day, month and year of birth in MVC. I'd like to calculate the age and disallow registration for guys which are younger than 18 dinamically. Though JS.

Something similar to what is shown in this image:
[image]

This is done by using DataAnnotations and EditorFor. The actual source code is similar to what follows. How should I modify to validate 3 controls together?

```
[Required(ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof (Resources), 
          ErrorMessageResourceName = "RequiredField")]
[Range(1, 31)]
[LocalizedDisplayName(typeof (RA.Resources), "RegistrationDayOfBirth")]
public int BirthDay { get; set; }

[Required(ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof (Resources), 
          ErrorMessageResourceName = "RequiredField")]
[Range(1, 12)]
[LocalizedDisplayName(typeof (RA.Resources), "RegistrationMonthOfBirth")]
public int BirthMonth { get; set; }

[Required(ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof (Resources), 
          ErrorMessageResourceName = "RequiredField")]
[Range(1800, int.MaxValue, ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof (Resources),
       ErrorMessageResourceName = "MoreThanFieldRequired")]
[LocalizedDisplayName(typeof (RA.Resources), "RegistrationYearOfBirth")]
public int BirthYear { get; set; }

[LocalizedDisplayName(typeof (RA.Resources), "RegistrationDateOfBirth")]
public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }
```

Comment: I'm not sure what value your image is providing - the question was quite clear without it...

Comment: What about inheriting from IValidatableObject and implementing IEnumerable<ValidationResult> IValidatableObject.Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)? I'm trying that way and seems very easy..

Comment: Hmm, that too would work, but won't provide you with a client-side option either (i.e. you'll need a server round trip/postback) to get the validation to appear.

Comment: @Zhaph-BenDuguid: I've accepted your answer, later I would like to add the client side solution I've adopted.. can I add to yours or better to the wikified?

Comment: You're welcome to add to mine, it's a collaborative site after all :) I was about to dig out an implementation using `ValidationAttribute, IClientValidatable, IMetadataAware` to enable the client side to know what it's doing, but if you're sorted ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to stick with the 3 field approach, as well as have dynamic validation (i.e. deny me access today if my 18th birthday is tomorrow, but let me in tomorrow) you're going to need to get creative.

You'll then need to create a custom validator, and some custom attributes to go with it.

How you go about this depends on the amount of work you want to do, and where you want to apply the validation logic.

## Server-side only validation

The simplest option is to define this on the class itself - however this will limit you to server-side validation only.

Create a custom attribute that is applied at the class level that expects there to be three fields on the class (I've added an interface to make this simpler and not require reflection) and validate this as required:

```
// Interface to define individual fields:
public interface IHasIndividualDateOfBirth
{
  int BirthDay { get; set; }
  int BirthMonth { get; set; }
  int BirthYear { get; set; }
}

// Note new class level attribute, and interface declaration:
[MinAge(AgeInYears = 18)]
public class Birthday: IHasIndividualDateOfBirth
{
  [Required]
  [Range(1, 31)]
  public int BirthDay { get; set; }
  [Required]
  [Range(1, 12)]
  public int BirthMonth { get; set; }
  [Required]
  [Range(1800, 2200)]
  public int BirthYear { get; set; }

  public DateTime BirthDate { get; set; }
}

// Declare a new ValidationAttribute that can be used at the class level:
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class)]
public class MinAgeAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
  public int AgeInYears { get; set; }

  // Implement IsValid method:
  protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, 
                                              ValidationContext validationContext)
  {
    // Retrieve the object that was passed in as our DateOfBirth type
    var objectWithDob = validationContext.ObjectInstance 
                          as IHasIndividualDateOfBirth;

    if (null != objectWithDob)
    {
      // TODO: Handle invalid dates from the front-end (30 Feb for example)
      DateTime dateOfBirth = new DateTime(objectWithDob.BirthYear, 
                                          objectWithDob.BirthMonth, 
                                          objectWithDob.BirthDay);

      // Check that the age is more than the minimum requested
      if (DateTime.Now >= dateOfBirth.AddYears(AgeInYears))
      {
        return ValidationResult.Success;
      }

      return new ValidationResult("You are not yet 18 years old");
    }

    return new ValidationResult("Class doesn't implement IHasIndividualBirthday");
  }
}
```

While implementing `IValidatableObject` may seem simpler still, it isn't as flexible as using an attribute and also (like the class-based validation above) doesn't provide a way to perform client-side validation.

Other options would be to create a validator that depends on a number of other fields (in which case you would probably need to use reflection to look for other fields, and work out which ones go where) and you'd need to ensure you're only firing the validator once (rather than on every field), or to write a custom validator and editor for the DateTime property that instead of rendering a single field that you could drop a calendar control onto creates the three separate fields you're after.

## Client- and server-side validation

To get client-side validation working, you'll need to do this at the property level, which will require you to do some additional work - you could for example use the DateTime field you have on the model as a hidden field that is populated via JS as the user fills in the individual fields and then validate that.

Your attribute would then need to implement `IClientValidatable` which would enable you to hook into the client-side validation options and also render out some metadata on the elements to expose the age requirement:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property)]
public class MinAgeAttribute : ValidationAttribute, IClientValidatable
{
  public int AgeInYears { get; set; }

  protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value,
                                              ValidationContext validationContext)
  {
    // [Similar to before]
  }

  public IEnumerable<ModelClientValidationRule> GetClientValidationRules(
                                                        ModelMetadata metadata,
                                                        ControllerContext context)
  {
    return new[]
    {
      new ModelClientValidationMinAgeRule(ErrorMessage, AgeInYears)
    };
  }
}

public class ModelClientValidationMinAgeRule : ModelClientValidationRule
{
  public ModelClientValidationMinAgeRule(string errorMessage, int ageInYears)
  {
      ErrorMessage = errorMessage;
      // Validation Type and Parameters must be lowercase
      ValidationType = "minage";
      ValidationParameters.Add("ageinyears", ageInYears);
  }
}
```

Then for the client side you need to register some custom validators into jQuery.Validate or similar (I recommend your own JS file included in the `jqueryval` bundle):

```
$(function ($) {
  $.validator.addMethod("minage", function(value, element, params) {
    if ($(element).val() != '') {

      var ageInYears = params;

      // take date from BirthDate element and compare with ageInYears.
      return false;
    }
  });

  $.validator.unobtrusive.adapters.addSingleVal("minage", "ageinyears");
}(jQuery));
```

Comment: Added a community wiki to show the client-side of things.

Comment: Your answer is really great, and also thanks to Cris. I think this is one of the best combined work I've seen on this site from when I use it!

Comment: @Revious I've added in some stubs for client-side validation as well.

Answer (score 2):

Zhaph's answer is a good one, but it neglects to mention how to approach this from a client-side perspective, once you've implemented his solution. Essentially, he's switching the validation from the three individual fields to one new one, `BirthDate`. You would therefore need to include the validation result from this property on page, instead of the three individual fields. Typically, you would do something like:

```
<label for="@Html.IdFor(m => m.BirthMonth)">
    @Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.BirthDate)
</label>
<div>
    @Html.EditorFor(m => m.BirthMonth)
    @Html.EditorFor(m => m.BirthDay)
    @Html.EditorFor(m => m.BirthYear)
</div>
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.BirthDate)
```

Key points:

1. The label is for the first field of the group, so that clicking the label will get the user to the  field as it should. However, the actual value of the label is from the `BirthDate` field, so that it's represents the whole group of fields instead of just the first one, in this case, `BirthMonth`.
2. The validation message also comes from the `BirthDate` field, which would print something like "You are not yet 18 years old", based on Zhaph's implementation, just once.

for implementing the controls on the client side you can use JQuery plugins such as **jQuery Validation Plugin** and look at this article: [ASP.NET MVC Client Side Validation](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/718004/ASP-NET-MVC-Client-Side-Validation)

Comment: To make the client side validation is required to write JQuery code?

Comment: Yes, the code above only prints out the validation message from the server. Anytime you create a custom validation attribute, you are also responsible for implementing the client-side validation code, if you are using client-side validation.

Comment: I've added a section to my answer with a client-side approach as well - including implemtation of `IClientValidatable` and stubs for the actual unobtrusive jQuery validation methods :)